# How to find whether an application is installed in a device from web?

Tags: android

I created an android application and uploaded in my website. Is it possible to check from the web whether this application is installed in the device when someone is trying to download the application ? If it is installed, the user should get a prompt whether  to reinstall or not. If not the application should not be downloaded.

Thanks in advance...

regards, 
Vishakh

Comment: As far as I kow, this is not possible because you cannot questioning the mobiles internal data from a website, without finding a very good bug in the system

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember that's standard feature, android always asks if user wants to reinstall app or not. But that's definitely impossible to get this data from web.